# How to insert \Latex command in \section

Tags: sectioning, titles

I have written this code (in my LaTeX document)

```
\section{\Latex}
```

and it is the only that do not work.

There is a way to insert `\Latex` command in `\section` and - after - in the `\maketitle`?

I'm using:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = it
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,newverbs,xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\title{Condivisione di buone pratiche\\sulle applicazioni digitali nella didattica}
\author{Giacomo Alessandroni}
\date{ITIS ``Enrico Mattei''\\Urbino, \today}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

A seguire le piattaforme che ho maggiormente utilizzato...

[...]

\section{\Latex}

Bla, bla...

\end{document}
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Case matters, try `\LaTeX`

Comment: @daleif thaks and... shame of me

Comment: No worries, we've all done it at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX commands are case sensitive, so try

```
\LaTeX
```

instead